# How to fix error with import CKeditor: error TypeError: CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.queue is not a function

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have Domino server (9.0.1 FP10 on windows 7/64 6.1) when I include RichTextBox in my Xpage and load page, i will have error

```
@Fi&@Im&@In.js:274 dojo/parser::parse() error TypeError: 
 CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.queue is not a function
 at Object.$DDMp_ [as _postCreate] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:443)
 at Object.$DDMl_ [as postCreate] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:443)
 at Object.$DDDD_ [as create] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:163)
 at Object.$DDDC_ [as postscript] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:163)
 at new <anonymous> (dojo.js:15)
 at Object.$DDSv_ [as construct] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:274)
 at Object.<anonymous> (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:274)
 at Object.$DDSY_ [as map] (dojo.js:15)
 at Object.$DDSu_ [as _instantiate] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:274)
 at @Fi&@Im&@In.js:274
 (anonymous) @ @Fi&@Im&@In.js:274
dojo.js:15 TypeError: this.editor.getData is not a function
 at Object.$DDMu_ [as getValue] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:443)
 at x_sl.view__id1__id166__id167__id214_body1_rteSubmit [as listener] 
 at x_sl.xsl_r [as run] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:289)
 at _3.x_pls [as _processListeners] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:289)
 at _3.x_dfe [as _doFireEvent] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:289)
 at _3.x_fpar [as firePartial] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:289)
 at xaep_fpre (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:289)
 at _3.x_aep [as _attachEventOrPartial] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:289)
 at _3.x_apar [as attachPartial] (@Fi&@Im&@In.js:289)
 at documents.xsp?
```

How I can re-importing new version CKeditor?

How I can understand my server have old version of CKeditor, it use .query() function but when i open my page in web, it preloaded new version CKeditor when .query() change on .load(). When I use local server i dont have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a javascript file is not OK and throws an error (which kills the complete Dojo framework).

First you should disable resource aggregation & use uncompressed JS files. Add the following lines to your *xsp.properties* file:

- *xsp.client.resources.uncompressed=true*
- *xsp.resources.aggregate=false*

This gives you more information what JS code is not working.

If there are still problems with CKEditor, open your XPage with the URL parameter "*?x-ckeditor-debug=true*". You have to change your language settings in the browser to English ("en"), otherwise it will fail.

Then your CKEditor code is also uncompressed, which makes debugging a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for You answer but when i added "xsp.client.resources.uncompressed=true" and "xsp.resources.aggregate=false" i have new error.                                       
1) Error: multipleDefine
2) dojo/parser::parse() error TypeError: format.replace is not a function                              3) TypeError: Cannot read property 'initForEdit' of undefined                                          I don`t see old erorr about CKEditor but it still do not work.

Comment: Seems to be an AMD loader problem. Which other JS libraries are you using in your XPage?